# tinymce 4.5.1 missing border style on table

Tags: tinymce

this is my current setup of my tinymce :

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '.default-editor',
    height: 80,
    menubar: true,
    plugins: 'print preview fullpage searchreplace autolink directionality visualblocks visualchars fullscreen image link codesample table charmap hr toc insertdatetime advlist lists textcolor wordcount imagetools  contextmenu colorpicker textpattern',
    toolbar1: 'formatselect | forecolor backcolor | link | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify  | numlist bullist outdent indent  | removeformat',
});
```

I cannot find why the border style option on advanced tab of table properties is missing.

This is the advanced tab of my tinymce table properties

[image]

But the tinymce full featured is showing the border style on advanced tab

[image]

I cannot find what i've been missing in my set up to show the border style option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of TinyMCE are you running?  If I load TinyMCE via http://fiddle.tinymce.com/  and open that dialog the option is there:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/cvgaab

My guess is you are running an older TinyMCE release and updating to the current release will address this issue.

Comment: Forgot to add the version, mine is 4.5.1, I think i have to update my tinymce. Thanks!